# limit of sequence transformed random variable

Tags: limits, measure-theory

Let $f$ be some function with $\lim_{s\to\infty} f(s)=0$. Now consider the following inequality: $$f(s)<e^{-(s x)^2},$$ where $x$ is a random variable that is standard normal distributed. The question is whether the inequality is true for all possible realizations of $x \sim N(0,1)$ as $s\to \infty$. Clearly, both sides go to 0 in the limit. So whether or not this is true depends on the rate at which $f$ goes to 0 compared to the right hand side.

Now suppose we were to do a change of variables to $y=sx$ on the right hand side. Then an equivalent statement would be: Is $$f(s)<e^{-y^2}$$ true for all $y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $s\to\infty$? Now, however, fixing a particular $y$, the statement seems to be always true...

I find this discrepancy somewhat odd and I suspect that something is wrong how I treat the transformation here. But I am confused about where exactly my reasoning goes wrong.

Here are some thoughts:
I know that the transformation is not well-defined in the limit, so this could be one problem. Another thing is whether one can even fix a particular $y$ and validate the inequality pointwise. E.g., it could be that generally, it is not sufficient to fix a particular $y$ and show that for any such $y$ there exists an $s$ such that the inequality is true. Alternatively, it could also be that just in this context one cannot keep $y$ fixed given that the transformation itself does depend on $s$ (or, equivalently, given that the distribution of $y$ does depend on $s$).

It would be great if someone could clarify where exactly my reasoning goes wrong.

Comment: The inequality you are using means almost surely right? Or do you really want it to hold for every possible of the normal distribution?

Comment: Doing the transformation $y= sx$ and looking at one realization of $y$ is not appropriate here, I think. In your line of thought the realization is fixed and does not depend on $s$ anymore while the left hand side of the inequality  is still dependent on $s$.

Comment: Take for example $e^{-s^2}$ clearly for $-1<x < 1$ (that is when you get $e^{-(s^2(1-\varepsilon)^2)}\,,1>\varepsilon >0$) the inequality does not hold, so there is $P(-1<x <1)$ probability it wont hold.

Comment: @user90793. I am not fully sure if I understand. As long as I am not in the limit, aren't the two approaches the same? For instance, when I would be interested in the probability that the inequality holds, then the probability in terms of $y$ would be $P(-s<y<s)$, which given that the variance of $y$ is $s^2$) seems to be precisely the same as you had in terms of $x$.

Comment: @Bob. I do not understand how you interpret the inequality. Is it - for every fixed value of $s$ check the inequality, or is it -  for every realization of $x$ check the inequality for all $s$. Two those interpretations are not equivalent. If I was presented with an inequality where one side is random and the other is deterministic. I would interpret it intuitively as the second option: First take a realization of the random variable, and then check the inequality for all $s$.

Comment: @Bob, continuing my last comment. Here is an example of what I mean when I say that the two approaches are not equivalent: Let $x\sim U(0,1)$ and $f(s) = \frac{1}{s}, s>0$. And look at the inequality $f(s) < x$. If you fixed $s$ first, no matter how large $s$ is, there is probability that $x$ is large enough so that the inequality does not hold. However if you first pick $x$, there is always $s$ large enough for which the inequality holds.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38350/discussion-on-question-by-bob-limit-of-sequence-transformed-random-variable).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just to put together what I wrote in the comments:

When you change the variables, the way to think about the second inequality would be in terms of $f(\frac{y}{x})$ and not f(s). I.e. one can not assume that in the second inequality s would be independent of y and still be deterministic.

If you fix y, and then let s go to infinity, you are as a result varying x, which then would no longer have the same N(0,1) distribution, i.e. fixing y is a different problem, since even though s and x are independent, s and y are not.

In other words, if you are fixing y, then s is actually a random variable and not deterministic, i.e. $\frac{y}{x}$, taking values anywhere on ℝ and Cauchy distributed (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution), for which the probability that |s| is very large (and hence f(s) smaller than any arbitrary number) is 1−ϵ, since the Cauchy distribution has "very thick tails", e.g. enough so that its expectation does not even exist.

Thus the second inequality should be true with very high probability, although it does not mean what you want it to mean.

If you are fixing s, then s is measurable with respect to the trivial sigma algebra (since it is a constant RV), so (y|s) (y given s) would also be measurable with respect to the trivial sigma algebra, so essentially any event corresponding to (y|s), which seems to be your second inequality, is either a.s. true or a.s. false, which corroborates the inequality being a.s. true.

If in the second inequality you are taking s to be fixed, then the random variable you are considering is actually (y|s), which has to be measurable with respect to a trivial sigma algebra (since s is a constant RV), so hence (y|s) would also be a.s. constant ($s\mathbb{E}x = 0$), so the inequality would become f(s) < 1 as s goes to infinity, which is obviously true by assumption.

Changing variables for random variables always requires great care, since RVs are actually real-valued functions from a probability space, not numbers, so the logic involved will always be more complicated and the reasoning used for regular variables unsuited.

EDIT: to address concerns about the notation used in this answer, and to appeal to those who are familiar with the concept of conditional expectation as a random variable, (y|s) is not standard notation, but it is obviously highly suggestive of (and meant to denote) $\mathbb{E}(Y|\sigma(s))$, which is a constant random variable (it is a constant RV because of the conditioning on the trivial sigma algebra, the sigma is being trivial because the RV s is a constant RV).

Comment: Two problems with the edit: First, the notation (y|s), if it must be used (it must not), denotes a conditional distribution while E(Y|sigma(s)) denotes a conditional expectation. Using the former for the latter is misleading. Second, the notation E(Y|sigma(Z(omega))) simply does not exist (and for good reasons, being absurd). Canonical notations for the conditional expectation of Y conditionally on the sigma-algebra sigma(Z) are E(Y|Z) or E(Y|sigma(Z)).

Comment: No (y|s) is meant to denote a conditional expectation, NOT A DISTRIBUTION. It is not canonical notation; it is simplified notation because I did not want to assume that OP fully understood the concept of conditional expectation as being a random variable defined with respect to conditioning on a sigma algebra instead of a single event. Your pedantry is not scholarship; just because there is abuse of notation and non-standard notation does not mean that the argument is incorrect. Lastly, if $Z(\omega)$ is allowed to denote a function, then the notation $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z(\omega))$ is well-defined.

Comment: I never claimed that the notation was standard or canonical; the notion of conditional distribution is even more complex than that of conditional expectation, so I clearly was not expecting them to understand conditional distribution well if they did not understand conditional expectation. Please stop obsessing over my post just because you are misinterpreting my notation, which is admittedly sloppy but served its purpose to answer OP's question to their satisfaction, that is, in a way that appeals to the intuition while not conforming to standard practice/notation.

Comment: OK, I do not want to be dragged into yet another exhausting exchange over trivial matters, so let me state this once and for all as clearly as I can. 1. No textbook and no scholar use (y|s) to denote a conditional expectation. 2. When the notation (y|s) is met, it always denotes a conditional distribution. 3. No textbook and no scholar use E(Y|Z(omega)) to denote what is universally denoted E(Y|Z) or, equivalently, E(Y|sigma(Z)). Period.

Comment: I did not say any textbook or scholar did use such notation, and they shouldn't, because the notation is obviously sloppy and abuse of notation, which is meant more to convey a hand-wavey intuitive answer ("there's no $\mathbb{E}$ so it looks like a random variable and not a linear functional!"). I didn't think (y|s) would have been mistaken for a conditional distribution, but now that you point it out, I can understand why the notation is problematic for more knowledgeable persons. The idea was that since RV's are usually denoted with upper case letters, hence normally (Y|s) would be written,

Comment: but since OP used lower-case y for some reason, I decided to just stick/go with it and use that notation throughout the rest of the answer, both to make it more accessible to OP and to distinguish from (Y|s) which in most textbooks would denote a conditional distribution. I agree that my answer probably does and should give anyone who has read a graduate text on probability brain cancer, but then again the answer was meant for OP. A more knowledgeable likely would have foreseen the dangers inherent in a "change of variables" with respect to random variables. @Did

Comment: If you want to edit the answer to make it better conform to standard notation, feel free to do so. I know I was sloppy but I was satisfied with having disabused OP of the notion that the second inequality could be interpreted identically as the first inequality.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the answer seems like it depends specifically on the the function f(s). If you really want the answer to hold for every possible realization of the normal distribution however, and not just almost surely or in probability or something like that, then I would have to assume the answer is no for any function that did not go to zero *extremely* rapidly.

More precisely, N(0,1) can take any real value. So the inequality would literally have to fold for all x in R, which seems implausible to me in most cases.

If you use some function that goes to 0 faster than every conceivable exponential (maybe like the gamma function, since that generalizes the factorials on $R^+$?) it might have a chance of working.

Otherwise if the function is $O(e^{as^2})$ for any $a\in R$, then it does not seem possible this could hold for every realization of N(0,1).

Comment: Yes, initially I had in mind for every possible realization, but thinking through the case where it has to hold almost surely seems interesting as well.

Comment: One question about the case where it holds everywhere: Doesn't the answer depend on the order I would take the limit? I.e., do I fix a $s$ and then require that it holds for all $x$, or do I fix a $x$ and then make sure that for any possible $x$ there is a sufficiently large $s$ so that it holds. Of course, the latter doesn't help much with the original problem as $sx$ scales with $s$. But this is precisely where after the transformation there seemed to be a difference, since then for every possible $y$ there is a $s$ so that it holds.

Comment: Well when you do the change of variables, wouldn't the relevant inequality be in terms of $f(\frac{y}{x})$ and not $f(s)$? Depending on the value of x, one inequality would be much easier to satisfy than the other.

Comment: As regards the order of the limits: the way the question was phrased, I was under the impression that it would be like - "for arbitrary x (i.e. first fix an x) the limit as $s \rightarrow \infty$ holds". If you are interested only in the limiting behavior then fixing s probably is not of much use. But if you want the inequality to hold for all s, and not just "s suitably large", then I agree, you would have to check that both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Also if you fix y, and then let s go to infinity, you are as a result varying x, which then would no longer have the same N(0,1) distribution, i.e. fixing y is a different problem, since even though s and x are independent, s and y are not. Fixed s is measurable with respect to the trivial sigma algebra (since it is a constant RV), so (y|s) (y given s) would also be measurable with respect to the trivial sigma algebra, so essentially any event corresponding to (y|s), which seems to be your second inequality, is either a.s. true or a.s. false, which corroborates the inequality being a.s. true.